# ffmpegを手動でUbuntu18.04にインストールしたい

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg

なるべく環境を汚さずにインストールしたくて、自身で作成したフォルダにffmpegのファイルをDLしてそこにPATHを通す形でソフトを使用したいのですが、[公式サイト](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html)のどのファイルをDLしてPATHを通したら良いのか分かりません。
多くの解説サイトでは`apt install ffmpeg`での方法しか書かれていません。

どこかで`apt install`などはパスを通してるだけだと聞いたので手動でPATHを通せばインストール可能だと思うのですが、どなたか教えて頂けないでしょうか？

Comment: apt install が一番「環境を汚さない」手法だと思うけど、これを使いたくない理由が何かあるっすか？

Comment: ubuntuのパッケージ管理について調べたら、PATHを通すだけではなく、必要なソフトなども自動でインストールしてくれているようで、まだ分からない事だらけで発言している状態です。環境を汚さないのは`apt install`がどんなファイルをどこに保存しているのか分からなくて、それを一つのフォルダに入れて、PATHを通すだけで使用できれば削除する時もPATHを決してフォルダ削除でアンインストール出来ると思ってそれだと分かりやすくていいなと考えた次第です。seleniumのwebdriverをインストールした時、サイトからファイルDLとPATHを通すだけで使用できたのでこんな感じでインストール出来るといいなと思いました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"環境を汚す" というのは標準以外のディレクトリへ独自にインストールすることだと思うので、パッケージ管理に従った方が "汚れない" と個人的には思います。

---

あくまでパッケージを利用したくないということであれば、以下の手順でインストールする形になると思います。

#### ダウンロード & インストール手順

公式サイトの " Get packages & executable files" で Linux を選択し、"Linux Static Builds" の下の [リンク先](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) に移動。

注意書きでは "git master builds" がお勧めされてますが、ひとまず右側の "release" から利用しているOSに合わせたアーカイブを選択してダウンロード。(大抵のケースでは amd64 を選んでおけばOKでしょう)

```
$ curl -O https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-amd64-static.tar.xz
```

保存したアーカイブを展開

```
$ unxz -c ffmpeg-release-amd64-static.tar.xz | tar xvf -
```

展開されたディレクトリを PATH に追加

```
$ export PATH=~/ffmpeg-4.2.3-amd64-static:$PATH

$ which ffmpeg
~/ffmpeg-4.2.3-amd64-static/ffmpeg

$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 4.2.3-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
```

Comment: これには必要な依存ファイルなども`ffmpeg-release-amd64-static.tar.xz | tar xvf -`に含まれているのですか？

Comment: Linuxではconfigure→make→make installとコマンド入力でソースコードをコンパイルしてアプリケーションを導入するやり方もあるのですね。

Comment: アーカイブ名に `static` と付いているので、スタティックリンクでコンパイルされたバイナリだと思います。詳しい説明は脱線するので省きますが、このアーカイブに必要なものは含まれていると考えてください。

Comment: すいません。この環境変数は再起動時にはリセットされるので、.profileに記述する必要がありますか？あと`$ export PATH=~/ffmpeg-4.2.3-amd64-static:$`後半のドル記号は何を意味しているんですか？元々代入されている環境変数に影響を与えないように追加するという意味でしょうか？

Comment: 上記をホームディレクトリの`.bash_profile`に追加したらlsなどのコマンドが使用できなくなって焦りました。なんとか復旧できました。

Comment: 末尾が `$` で終わっていたのは私の書き損じです、失礼しました (回答本文も修正済みです。 / ご認識の通り、コマンドで実行しただけだと次回ログイン時に反映されないので、`.bashrc` や `.bash_profile` に追記する必要があります。

Answer (score 0):

Snappyでインストールするというのはどうでしょうか。
(日本語でよりわかりやすく解説しているサイトもあるかと思いますが)[公式サイト](https://snapcraft.io/blog/a-technical-comparison-between-snaps-and-debs)が言うところの

> Each snap is a compressed SquashFS package (bearing a .snap extension), containing all the assets required by an application to run independently, including binaries, libraries, icons, etc.

辺りが希望にかなっていると思います。

[インストール方法](https://snapcraft.io/install/ffmpeg/ubuntu):

```
sudo snap install ffmpeg
```

ちなみに、Ubuntu18.04だと[ソフトウェアセンター](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-ubuntu)からインストールした場合でも(`apt`でなく)`snap`が用いられます。

---

[Linuxbrew(Homebrew on Linux)](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux)もシステムが利用するライブラリ群とは独立して管理するという点では「環境を汚さない」に該当するかと思います。

- https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ffmpeg

ただ、こちらはsnappyと異なりffmpegだけで独立しているわけではなくLinuxbrew環境の中にインストールされるので、「Linuxbrew環境が汚れる」というふうには言えるかもしれません。

Comment: これについて記事でみました。aptと共存できてsnappyは独立した環境で動作していると聞きました。